# Smooth shading doesn't work in final Cycles render, why?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to fix this unexpected behavior of Blender, where smooth shading works everywhere, except the final render. I've read and tried all other Q&A I could find, but nothing really applies. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a subdivision surface modifier? If so, check to make sure the number of subdivisions are the same for the render as they are for the viewport.

Comment: No, all subdivisions are already applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify your normals are correct. Then turn on Normals Auto Smooth. An angle of 30 is good for most stuff.

[image]

Comment: The auto smooth did the trick! Though, I still do not understand why. The chocolate has it off and still renders smooth.

Comment: Spoke too soon. The problem didnt disappear. I ended up adding a new subdivision modifier.